# Updating a column with a column from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

Despite researching other postings, I have not been able to resolve the issue of not being able to updating a table with a column from another table.

```
update tab t1
set x1 = (select cast(x1 || '-' || x2 as char(9)) as x3 from tab t2 );
```

I am getting the following error:

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

but I'm not exactly sure how to get around this error. Any tips?

Comment: I'm curious about the exact error you're getting.  The problem is: you can only put one value in column x1 of a t1 row.  Here you want to put as many values as t2 has rows, into column x1 of each t1 row.  Your scalar select should return one or no values.

Comment: ERROR: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as 
an expression <= That's the error

Comment: That's what I expected.  Please create an SQL Fiddle with some data and your exact query, that way we'll give you a working solution.  http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is a one to one relation between the two tuples, both have a column y1.

```
update t1
   set x1 = (select cast(x1 || '-' || x2 as char(9)) as x3
               from t2
               where t2.y1 = t1.y1);
```

Comment: I should also elaborate that the two tables are the same. The table providing the new column to t1 is also t1 as well. I updated my response.

Comment: So the relation isn't one on one.   If what you say is true, there is no need to join.  `update t1 set x1 = cast(x1 || '-' || x2 as char(9))`

Comment: It would also help if you didn't lie.  `updating a table with a column from another table` vs. `two tables are the same`.

Comment: Lie is a strong word. I honestly didn't think it would have mattered whether it's the same table or not.

Comment: I assure you, it matters immensely.

Comment: Right, but there's a difference between lying as your are accusing vs ambiguity. Nevertheless, your suggestion worked. So thank you.

Comment: It's been a pleasure.